# Generate vector patterns from a mask?

Tags: procedural-art

I'm working on a project for which i'll need a lot of motherboard graphics like this one.

[image]

Since it will be a lot of work to do it by hand, I was wondering if a tool to automatize it would exist.

The idea would be to give the software a mask and it would generate the image.
[image]

Ideally, I would need more parameters - for example, I would like to be able to select patterns to place in the pictures on the top of the regular "paths" so I could generate more complex images:
[image]

Does anyone know if such a tool exists ?

found while searching:

- [jsplacement](https://windmillart.net/?p=jsplacement), but you can't give an input mask
- [Create-A-Maze](http://maze5.de/maze-5/create-a-maze/), which supports masks inputs
- [Generating mazes from pictures, or “Masking Entropy”](https://medium.com/@G3Kappa/generating-mazes-from-pictures-or-masking-entropy-4d050d148539)
- [P5.js](https://p5js.org/)

But none of them is exactly what I'm looking for.
Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: Seems like the type of thing a custom brush would be good for

Answer (score 2):

One idea: Circuit boards can be designed with circuit board design software. As functional electronics this is like bunk, so you probably can input quite random connection and part lists. But the circuit board outlines must be freely selectable.

There's plenty of free and paid circuit board design software available. The high end programs, of course, cost a fortune because in addition of placing parts and wires they either also understand  electrical functionality, production process, product structure as a whole or all of them.

An electronic design engineer probably would be a good partner in this art project.

Comment: @Billy Kerr Long time ago some artists started to make totally non-functional machines. Their work got ridicule "bonk". Much later (in 1990's) one artist did it again and took name Bonk into use intentionally. A link https://www.fastcompany.com/26503/finnish-company-thats-never-done

Comment: In the UK "bonk" means "to have sex".  LOL.